# What is the difference between doughnut and krapfen?

Tags: doughnuts

I have been in a shop where you were able to see how they made doughnuts. The first thing I thought was that they were krapfen.

Are there any differences between krapfen, and doughnut? Does one use different ingredients?

Comment: No, it is the same thing in English and in German.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There doesn't appear to be any difference. Wikipedia says "In English-speaking countries, Berliners are usually called doughnuts and are usually filled with jam, jelly, custard or whipped cream", and [this page](http://home.comcast.net/~osoono/ethnicdoughs/krapfen/krapfen.htm) says "The English translation of krapfen is cruller or doughnut". There are so many variations of filling, topping, shape and so forth that it is hard to establish a single identity anyhow.

Comment: Cruller and donuts are different; a cruller is a fried pastry, while a donut is fried dough. The fact they are different enough is also evidenced in the Wikipedia article, where it is reported that the _chain of doughnut shops stopped carrying traditional crullers, claiming that the hand-shaped treats were too labor-intensive, and couldn't be simulated with new machines for mixing doughnut batter_. I have eaten krapfen in Italy (I think artisan is the correct word for the shop); the difference I could note between a donut and krapfen is that a krapfen doesn't have a hole, and [continue] …

Comment: … donuts can have a variety of toppings (while I saw krapfens with just two kinds of toppings).

Comment: Filled doughnuts in English usually don't have holes either.